# How to use events in NanoGallery2's API

Tags: javascript, nanogallery

I'm trying to use [NanoGallery2](https://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/) in my web application and it's *nearly* fantastic, but a couple of glaring omissions from the API (e.g. handling the display of image information) and the idiosyncratic documentation are driving me crazy.

Anyway, the [API documentation](https://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/api.html) lists a number of available events and callbacks. I have no trouble using the callbacks to trigger my own functionality, e.g.

```
$("#nanogallery2").nanogallery2({
  items: images,
  fnImgDisplayed: onImageDisplayed,
  "lightboxNextImage.nanogallery2": onImageDisplayed,
  thumbnailHoverEffect2: "scale120|labelSlideUp|toolsAppear", 
});

function onImageDisplayed() {
  alert("Image Displayed");
}
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to trigger my own functionality when any of the events fire. I'm pretty certain that I'm doing it wrong, but no variation I've tried works. I'm particularly interested in the `lightboxNextImage` and `lightboxPreviousImage` events. In the documentation all of the event names are listed with a `.nanogallery2` suffix (e.g. `lightboxNextImage.nanogallery2`) so I'm guessing they aren't used in the same way as callbacks but I've tried everything I can think of. Things I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
$("#nanogallery2").nanogallery2({
  items: images,
  "lightboxNextImage.nanogallery2": onImageDisplayed,
  thumbnailHoverEffect2: "scale120|labelSlideUp|toolsAppear", 
});

function onNextImage() {
  alert("Next Image")
}
```

```
$("#nanogallery2").nanogallery2({
  items: images,
  lightboxNextImage: onImageDisplayed,
  thumbnailHoverEffect2: "scale120|labelSlideUp|toolsAppear", 
});

function onNextImage() {
  alert("Next Image")
}
```

```
$("#nanogallery2").nanogallery2({
  items: images,
  lightboxNextImage.nanogallery2: onImageDisplayed,
  thumbnailHoverEffect2: "scale120|labelSlideUp|toolsAppear", 
});

function onNextImage() {
  alert("Next Image")
}
```

That last one even throws up IntelliSense errors because of the period in the key name, but I was getting desperate.

Can anyone put me out my misery? I've made a Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/philipstratford/pen/OJyvRye) in which I've been trying my various fruitless methods.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, I was being completely stupid and this issue only arose because it's midnight and I'm tired. For the benefit of any other tired soul finding their way here, the solution is to add an event listener to the code like this:

```
$("#nanogallery2").on("lightboxNextImage.nanogallery2", function () {
    alert("Next Image");
});
```

This uses jQuery but since NanoGallery2 is a jQuery plugin that shouldn't be a problem. I've created an updated Codepen with the working solution [here](https://codepen.io/philipstratford/pen/ExVeoKY?editors=1010).

This came to me 30 seconds after posting the question. Always the way, isn't it?